# How to return node if Constraints has violated

Tags: neo4j

I have the following scenario: a unique key X for Y. node If I try to create another node with the key X, want it to be made a new relationship with Y and is not created a new node.
Not to create a new node, the utilizer constraints. But I can not return it.

Thanks for any help.

[EDITED to include info from comments]

I need to return the node if already exists. Like this:

```
MATCH (n:Provider)
WHERE (n.UUID = "7223044e46d1b867")
MATCH (user:User {Username:"jefersonanjos.8"})
MERGE (node:Test {HashKey:'"6ad6a533a9c1b62704623bd982d1a434"'})
ON CREATE SET node.HashKey="6ad6a533a9c1b62704623bd982d1a434", node.AuthorImg=packer.CoverUrl, node.AuthorTitle='ok'
ON MATCH SET node.lastsee='bla'
MERGE n-[r:relation {Datecreate:635800177899216771}]->(node)
return node
```

But this query doesn't return `node`.

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED to reflect new info from comments]

The problem was that the first `MERGE` used a `HashKey` property that wrapped the value in single quotes as well as double-quotes, causing it to always create a new node instead of finding an existing node:

```
MERGE (node:Test {HashKey:'"6ad6a533a9c1b62704623bd982d1a434"'})
```

Fixing that issue, and simplifying a bit (to avoid setting the `HashKey` again), the following should work:

```
MATCH (n:Provider)
WHERE (n.UUID = "7223044e46d1b867")
MATCH (user:User {Username:"jefersonanjos.8"})
MERGE (node:Test {HashKey:"6ad6a533a9c1b62704623bd982d1a434"})
ON CREATE SET node.AuthorImg=packer.CoverUrl, node.AuthorTitle='ok'
ON MATCH SET node.lastsee='bla'
MERGE n-[r:relation {Datecreate:635800177899216771}]->(node)
return node;
```

Comment: I need to return the node if already exist. Link this:
MATCH (n:Provider)
WHERE (n.UUID = "7223044e46d1b867")
MATCH (user:User {Username:"jefersonanjos.8"})
MERGE (node:Test {HashKey:'"6ad6a533a9c1b62704623bd982d1a434"'})
ON CREATE
SET node.HashKey="6ad6a533a9c1b62704623bd982d1a434", node.AuthorImg=packer.CoverUrl, node.AuthorTitle='ok'
on match set node.lastsee='bla'
MERGE n-[r:relation {Datecreate:635800177899216771}]->(node)
return node <code>. 

but this query doesn't return node.

Comment: I have updated your question with the above info. Are you sure that both `MATCH` clauses succeed? What do you get from this query: `MATCH (n:Provider {UUID:"7223044e46d1b867"})
MATCH (user:User {Username:"jefersonanjos.8"})
RETURN n, user;`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. the problem was the order of the merge, the query above is correct. Except the double quotes here: HashKey:'"6ad6a533a9c1b62704623bd982d1a434"'.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer to represent what I believe is the correct solution. Also, I have simplified the query a bit, since you do not need to set the `HashKey` again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, the problem was the order of the merge.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details about what the problem was, and show your new query that fixes the problem? This may help others.